Firebase Cloud Function: Error loading TensorFlow model - tf.node.loadLayersModel not a function
In firebase cloud function I'm trying to run a tenserflow model. But I keep getting the error: tf.node.loadLayersModel is not a function. Does anyone know what I might do wrong?
exports.runPredictionOnUpload = functions.firestore
    .document('modeltest/{docId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const docId = context.params.docId;
    const document = snap.data();
    const data = document.data;

    if (!data) {
      await db.collection('modeltest').doc(docId).update({
        status: 'error',
        error: 'Data field is missing',
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      const file = storage.file('modelTest/ModelAugustus.h5');
      const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'ModelAugustus.h5'); 
      console.log('Model saved at:', tempFilePath);
      await file.download({ destination: tempFilePath });
    
      console.log('Model downloaded to:', tempFilePath);
    
      console.log('Loading model...');
      const model = await tf.node.loadLayersModel('file://' + tempFilePath);
      console.log('Model loaded successfully.');

      const inputTensor = tf.tensor([data]); 
      const prediction = model.predict(inputTensor);
      const predictionValue = prediction.arraySync()[0];

      await db.collection('modeltest').doc(docId).update({
        prediction: predictionValue,
        status: 'done',
      });
      fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error running prediction:', error);
      await db.collection('modeltest').doc(docId).update({
        status: 'error',
        error: error.message,
      });
    }
});


Why are you using tf.node.loadLayersModel instead of tf.loadLayersModel as shown in the documentation?
